# How to make a cylinder with bottom that shows hidden part of edge as dashed curve

Tags: graphics3d

I am learning a bit about [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) and found a nice feature in its graphics, that I am having hard time duplicating with `Graphics3D`. It is making a `Cylinder`, where the bottom will have part of its edge, that is behind the current view, show up as dashed lines. Ofcourse the `Cylinder` will have to be a little transparent to see the edge (using `Opacity`).

Another obstacle I found, is that one can't `Inset` 3D object inside another 3D object in *Mathematica*. I hope this will become possible in future versions.

Here is the [latex question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182976/creating-cylinder-with-bottom-node-shape-in-tikz-pgf) that shows how this is done in TikZ. Here is screen shot of the final shape (the letter `A` is not needed)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is what I tried: Make cylinder, remove its EdgeForm, make another cylinder to use for the bottom part, which is very thin, and have its edge be dashed.

But this does not really solve the problem, as I need to have the edge that is "behind" the current view be dashed.

The reason for asking, is not just for fun, but this will actually make the disk appear more real if it is possible to make the behind view edge dashed (or other color) from the front facing edge. So this can be useful feature for many other 3D objects making.

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[], Yellow, 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g2 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Dashed, Red]], FaceForm[], 
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, .01}}, 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now combined

```
   Graphics3D[{First@g1, First@g2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Close, but no cigar.

Comment: Take a look at this brilliant answer of Silvia: [45435](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45435/5478)

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the link. I did not know about it. But when trying it, it make static raster image. Like this `g = Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]];
DashedGraphics3D[g, Lighting -> "Neutral"]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GMYra.png) which works, and is very nice. But I was thinking of an actual 3D graphics, not rasterized version, which I can rotate and move and use in animation, etc.. yet still have this feature. May be I am asking too much come to think about?

Comment: Ok, vote retracted :)

Comment: This answer [20945](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/dashed-mesh-behind-3d-object/21079#21079) does something kind of similar.  You might be interested in the control for rotating it.  This one [28600](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28600/how-to-get-rid-of-the-perspective-effect-in-a-3d-graphics/28691#28691) also has a 3D rotation control which controls the image rendered inside it.

Comment: Related: [(20973)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20973/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not just what you requested but perhaps a bit closer to the tikz  rendering.

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[{Thick}], Glow[Pink], Black, 
    Cylinder[]}, Boxed -> False];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[{Thick}], Glow[Pink], Black, 
    Cylinder[]}];
GraphicsGrid[{{g1, g2}}]
```

[image: cans]

Answer (score 11):

Well, it was fairly quick for such a simple figure.  David Carraher's solution is simpler, except that the envelope is not drawn.

```
DynamicModule[{vv = {0, 0, 1}, vp = {3.2, 2., 4.}}, 
 Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[], Yellow, 
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]},
   {Directive[Thick, Dashed, Red], 
    Line[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}]],
    Line[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}]]},
   {Directive[Thick, Red],
    Dynamic@
     With[{angle = ArcTan[vp[[1]], vp[[2]]], width = ArcCos[1/Norm[vp]]},
      {If[vp[[3]] > 0, 
        Line[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, angle - width, angle + width, width/30}]],
        Line[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}]]],
       If[vp[[3]] < 0, 
        Line[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 1}, {t, angle - width, angle + width, width/30}]],
        Line[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}]]],
       Line[Append[Through[{Cos, Sin}[angle - width]], #] & /@ {0, 1}],
       Line[Append[Through[{Cos, Sin}[angle + width]], #] & /@ {0, 1}]}
      ]
    }
   }, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The dashed lines change as the object is rotated in the front end.

Comment: Oh man, that `ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]` trick is neat. I know I'm going to be using that in the future.